# Is a way to quickly set screen refresh rate

Tags: windows, windows-8, batch, refresh-rate

Is a way to quickly set refresh rate instead of right-click on Desktop

```
Screen Resolution -> Advanced Settings -> Monitor
```

and in center Monitor Settings screen refresh rate with dropdown

Or just only to show Advanced Settings with Monitor tab

And is it possible to do it in `.bat`?

Comment: You might be interested in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324290/batch-command-to-change-the-resolution-of-a-computer

Comment: @RamonRobben that questions is about setting the screen properties not getting them.

Comment: @DavidPostill the words "get to refresh rate" confused me I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Comment: @DavidPostill Indeed it's inapropriate, but people sometimes ask a question faster than they should and it doesn't mean what they wanted it to mean at first. Also, this question is not a duplicate one, as the link you gave is for Screen Resolution, not Screen refresh rate.

Comment: @Darksoulpk68 Reopened and answer edited.

Comment: yes sorry I asked too fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is the closest I've been able to do.**

I've created a text file.

typed in:

> desk.cpl

Then Save as

> desk.cpl
>
> Make sure it saves as `.cpl` and not as `.cpl.txt`

Double click it, and it shows you Screen resolution settings.

EDIT:
Found [this](http://tools.taubenkorb.at/change-screen-resolution/) a minute ago, you might want to give it a try.

Comment: ChangeScreenResolution.exe is cool :)

Comment: ChangeScreenResolution doesnt appear to work with Windows 10 CE

Comment: -1. This opens Settings app.

Answer (score 11):

#### Is there a way to quickly get the refresh rate?

You can do this from a `cmd` shell or in a batch file using `wmic`.

Example:

```
> wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller get currentrefreshrate
CurrentRefreshRate
60
```

---

#### Is there a way to quickly set the refresh rate?

[nircmd](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/) from [nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) can be used to **set** the refresh rate.

> **NirCmd Command Reference - setdisplay**
>
> ```
> setdisplay {monitor:index/name} [width] [height] [color bits] {refresh rate} {-updatereg} {-allusers}
> ```
>
> Changes your display settings.
>
> - The [width] and [height] parameters represents the number of pixels on your screen.
> - The [color bits] parameter represents the number of colors shown on your screen (8 - 256 color, 16 - 16bit color, 24 - 24bit color, and so
>     on).
> - {refresh rate} is an optional parameter that specifies the monitor refresh rate.
> - If you specify the {-updatereg} parameter, the new settings will be saved in the Registry.
> - If you specify both {-updatereg} and {-allusers} parameters, the new settings will be saved in the Registry for all users.
> - If you have multiple monitors, you can use the optional monitor parameter, which specifies for which monitor you want to change the
>     display settings. You can specify the monitor by index (0 for the
>     first monitor, 1 for the second one, and so on) or by specifying a
>     string in the system monitor name. The monitor name can be found in
>     the Device manager of Windows: Right click on the monitor item, and
>     then choose 'Properties'. The string displayed in the 'location' field
>     is the monitor name.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> setdisplay 800 600 24 -updatereg
> setdisplay 1024 768 24 90
> setdisplay 1024 768 8
> setdisplay monitor:1 1024 768 24 90
> setdisplay monitor:name1 1024 768 24 90
> ```

Source [NirCmd Command Reference - setdisplay](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/setdisplay.html)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: Well, this solution seems better than mine, I tried finding a way to do it using the command line, but was unable, I will make sure to save this link for future reference, I already know wmic (And use it some times to get process info) but I could not find information on getting Refresh rate, and here it is. +1

Comment: @asmith Yeah, `wmic` is cool :)

Comment: I want to access not get these property

Comment: What do you mean by access? The ability to change them? Or do you want to use then in some sort of script (like a batch file)?

Comment: yes I want to set/change refresh rate but faster

Answer (score 1):

## Own answer

For other people

**Yes** it is possible I did this in .bat:

```
ChangeScreenResolution.exe /f=75 /d=0
```

ChangeScreenResolution.exe **must be downloaded**

It not must be 75 in `/f` (but different than you have refresh rate) don't forget about `/d`

Thanks for ChangeScreenResolution.exe

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way to quickly get the refresh rate?**

This is possible using vbscript:

```
On Error Resume Next

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_VideoController")

For Each objItem in colItems

  objItem.CurrentHorizontalResolution
  Wscript.Echo "Current: " & objItem.CurrentRefreshRate
  objItem.InstalledDisplayDrivers
  Wscript.Echo "Max: " & objItem.MaxRefreshRate
  Wscript.Echo "Min: " & objItem.MinRefreshRate

Next
```

Just take that and save it in a file anyname.vbs
Make sure it has the extension vbs
In Notepad, when you save, just use quotes (") save like this "yourfilename.vbs"

Then you can just double click (single click if you have stettings set to that) on the file and you should get popup boxes telling you the current refresh rate, Max and Min the refresh rate can be.

Answer (score 0):

This is very suboptimal but can be somehow useful.

1. Type command (in terminal or by <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>):

   ```
   rundll32.exe display.dll, ShowAdapterSettings 0`
   ```

   This opens generic monitor properties dialog, see image. (`0` is an index of monitor #1).
2. Refresh rates are in "Monitor" tab
3. (bonus) You can check supported configurations for monitor by pressing "List of modes" button.

[image]